# Image would not show up in html5

Tags: html

Recently I downloaded a website template from bootstrap
and I want to edit some of the images in it.
even though I changed the source of the image with the image I want to replace with, nothing shows up in the site.
I do not think it is the path problem because it works fine with other images in the folder (but the other images were there when I downloaded the template)
I am not sure whether the image is the issue here

these are the codes of other images that works fine

```
<div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 team_col">
                <div class="team_item d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-start text-center">
                    <div class="team_image"><img src="images/team_4.jpg" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="team_content">
                        <div class="team_title"><a href="#">Noah Smith</a></div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I only changed the src part of it 
when I checked the specific part in development tool mode it shows like img 0x0

Answer (score 1):

make sure your image path

Noah Smith

hope so it will helpful for you